# Rendering Text Name as Component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a javascript object that looks something like this:

```
export const iconBoxes = [
  {
    ...
    icon: 'Lightbulb',
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    icon: 'Sun',
    ...
  }
]
```

I then map through that object in a React component as follows:

```
{iconBoxes.map(box => {
  return (
    <Box>
        ...
        <Icon as={box.icon} />
        ...
    </Box>
  )
})}
```

The `as` prop is from S[tyled Components](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop).

With that said, this does NOT work.   If I were to hand code it like this, however, it would work:

```
<Box>
  ...
  <Icon as={Lightbulb} />
  ...
</Box>
```

With `Lightbulb` coming from a `react-icon`:

```
import { FaRegLightbulb as Lightbulb } from 'react-icons/fa'
```

My question is, how can I get this to work when pulling in the name from the js object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, box.icon is just a string and what you want is a component. Styled component cannot understand this string because it's not a HTML tag.
So what you can do is map all the icon components you need in an object, and then pass the correct one according to box.icon.

You'll end up with something like this

```
import { FaRegLightbulb } from 'react-icons/fa'

const allIcons = {
  "Lightbulb": FaRegLightbulb,
  ...
}


<Icon as={allIcons[box.icon]} />
```

Comment: Thanks -- I created a variation of your solution and it worked perfectly.  Basically, I just changed updated my js object so that icon referenced a component (instead of a string).  Something like this:  `icon: FaRegLightbulb`.